# RSA Decryption using private key in NodeJs

Tags: java, node.js, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I am integrating a third-party API service, for security they have asked us to exchange information in an encrypted format. So, they have asked me to create an RSA public/private key and share the public key with them.

This is what they told me to do

Public Key certificate in 4096 bit. For encryption and decryption. (Zip File) OR Public key Self-signed certificate required(In 4096-bit format). Certificate format should be X.509 Certificate should start with “Begin Certificate” and end with “End Certificate”

### Encryption Process:-

1. Asymmetric Encryption(RSA_Encrypt) with RSA 4096 bit Public Key(Certificate), with mode/padding as ECB/PKCS1.
2. Base64Encode.
3. In Encryption Process Partner should use our Public Key Certificate.

### Decryption Process:-

1. Base64Decode
2. Asymmetric Decryption(RSA_Decrypt) by using Partner private Key certificate.

So, I ran the following command and gave them the public key certificate

```
openssl req -x509 -sha256 -nodes -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout private.key -out public.pem
```

And, on my end, I have written the following functions to encrypt using their public key and decrypt using my private key

```
async function RSA_Encrypt(str) {
    const publicKey = 
    fs.readFileSync(path.resolve("./their/UAT_PUBLIC_CERT.txt"), "utf8");
    const buffer = Buffer.from(str);
    const encrypted = publicEncrypt({ key: publicKey, padding: 
   constants.RSA_PKCS1_PADDING }, buffer);
   return encrypted.toString("base64");
}

async function RSA_Decrypt(str) {
    const privateKey = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve("./my/private.key"), 
    "utf8");
    const buffer = Buffer.from(str, "base64");
    const decrypted = privateDecrypt({ key: privateKey, padding: 
    constants.RSA_PKCS1_PADDING }, buffer);
    return decrypted.toString("utf8");
}
```

Now, I am sending the request to them by encrypting the request body with `RSA_Encrypt` function. They are responding back with an encrypted response, upon decrypting the response using the `RSA_Decrypt` function I am getting the following error

```
error:04065072:rsa routines:RSA_EAY_PRIVATE_DECRYPT:padding check failed
```

Also, I've tested the encryption using my public key and decryption using my private key which is working fine. Here are the functions I've written for test purpose,

```
function RSA_Encrypt(str) {
    const publicKey = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve("./my/public.pem"), "utf8");
    const buffer = Buffer.from(str);
    const encrypted = crypto.publicEncrypt({ key: publicKey, padding: 
    crypto.constants.RSA_PKCS1_PADDING }, buffer);
    return encrypted.toString("base64");
}

function RSA_Decrypt(str) {
    const privateKey = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve("./my/private.key"), "utf8");
    const buffer = Buffer.from(str, "base64");
    const decrypted = crypto.privateDecrypt({ key: privateKey, padding: 
    crypto.constants.RSA_PKCS1_PADDING }, buffer);
    return decrypted.toString("utf8");
}
```

I think this is some padding or mode issue, but unable to figure it out on my own. Can I specify ECB mode in `privateDecrypt` function? The encryption on their side is most probably happening in JAVA, so is there anything I am missing out in NodeJs?

Comment: Even the openssl command is giving the same error, I think it is something related to the mismatch keys, I'll keep you updated

Comment: ` openssl rsautl -decrypt -in ./encrypted.raw.txt -out ./decrypted.txt -inkey ./private.key`

Comment: Since the 2nd test is successful, it seems to work principally. You could try to analyze the problematic ciphertext. Use `crypto.constants.RSA_NO_PADDING` for _decryption_. Then the padding should not be removed (so no error can be caused). For PKCS#1 v1.5 the decrypted data should have the format `EM = 0x00 || 0x02 || PS || 0x00 || M`. The length of `EM` is the size of the modulus (4096 bits here). `PS` are pseudo random bytes. `M` is the actual message.  This may allow further conclusions to be drawn (corrupted ciphertext, different paddings, keys that do not match).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @Topaco. I'm investigating this out. WIll keep you updated.

Comment: Hi, I tried with RSA_NO_PADDING I got the response which is not in a readable format? It has corrupted letters. Is it the issue with the key?

Comment: You should display the decrypted (still padded) data hexadecimal encoded, i.e. `decrypted.toString('hex')`. PKCS#1v1.5 padding can be identified by a leading `0x0002`. Additionally, `PS` and `M` are separated by a `0x00`. OAEP is harder to detect but a `0x00` at the beginning is defined. If both are not met, probably either the keys do not match or the ciphertext is corrupt. The length of the Base64 decoded ciphertext should also be checked and be 512 bytes here (for a 4096 bits key).

Comment: I would check the keys (i.e. whether the private key on your side and the certificate/public key on the other side match). If this is OK, it might be useful to check the sent and the received ciphertext (prior you could check if the Base64 decoded ciphertext is 512 bytes long).

Comment: Hi, the issue has been resolved. It turned out that the other party was using a different key for encryption.